# Exporting a model to be implemented in mobile app

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-automl

We tested Cloud AutoML Vision product, the results are amazing 96% accuracy. 
So what we did so far was: upload labeled dataset, train, evaluate so we have a MODEL.

Further we want to Export this model and implement on a iOS app.

- But how do we export from Cloud AutoML?
- What formats are supported?

(did we missed something? we want in the end to get a .mlmodel file, we can use a converter but first we need to export some format).

Comment: @rhaertel80 what's your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

Model export feature is currently not supported in Cloud AutoML Vision.

The team is aware of this feature request. You can star and keep an eye on: https://issuetracker.google.com/113122585 for updates.

Comment: What's the business value then? How do you do anything with the AutoML Vision. Any alpha?

Comment: We are aware of this feature request. You can keep an eye on: https://issuetracker.google.com/113122585 for updates.

Answer (score 1):

The export functionality has been since added and is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/deploy

It seems the easiest way to do so is in the UI.

> You can export an image classification model in either generic
>   Tensorflow Lite format, Edge TPU compiled TensorFlow Lite format, or
>   TensorFlow format